# Handle Azure Virtual Machine deletion with Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Does anyone know how to implement this mention in the terraform documentation of [backup_protected_vm](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/backup_protected_vm) on azure?
[image]

I am exactly in the case where I want to delete a virtual machine without deleting its backup. I don’t see at all how to modify this property right after the creation of the backup in the code.

```
#Get Backup policy
data "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "backup_policy" {
  name                = var.backup_policy_name
  resource_group_name = var.recovery_vault.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = var.recovery_vault.name
}

# Add VM in Backup Recovery Vault
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "backup_vm" {
  resource_group_name = var.recovery_vault.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = var.recovery_vault.name
  source_vm_id        = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
  backup_policy_id    = data.azurerm_backup_policy_vm.backup_policy.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.extension_diskencryption
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do correctly, here's how you can handle it:

To allow the deletion of a VM without deleting its backup, you can use `lifecycle` meta-argument in the `azurerm_backup_protected_vm` resource block.
`ignore_changes` will prevent Terraform from recreating the resource when the `source_vm_id` changes or is removed.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "backup_vm" {
  resource_group_name = var.recovery_vault.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = var.recovery_vault.name
  source_vm_id        = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.vm.id
  backup_policy_id    = data.azurerm_backup_policy_vm.backup_policy.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_virtual_machine_extension.extension_diskencryption
  ]

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      source_vm_id,
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I thought about it, but the creation of the vm with the activation of the backup is inside a module that I use with a for_each to create several vm. The problem is that when I remove the vm from the list provided to the module, it removes all resources related to the module. It's quite logical so I'm testing it out of the module even though I don't really like having to do that.

Comment: In that case, you could create a separate module to manage the backups?

That will let you maintain the VMs and their backups in separate modules.

This way deleting a VM would not affect the associated backup. 

The for_each loop in the module "backup" block would iterate over the created VMs and set up the backups independently.